# Azure virtual machine in stopped state and can't start

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Azure VM that I created manually and deployed some services on it. Now all the sudden it is in a stopped state and I can't start it anymore. Below is the error message that I get when I try to start it.

> Failed to start virtual machine Failed to start the virtual machine
>   'xxxxxxxxx'. De bewerking d329ae99fc74571693e4e5590ad38ef4 is mislukt:
>   Cannot perform the operation on a stopped deployment..

I didn't do any deployment. The machine was installed manually. Please tell me this can be recovered since a lot of hours went into this. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Not much detail to go on. Plus, this is probably a better fit at ServerFault, since this isn't programming related.

Comment: Suggesting this may be why this issue is occurring: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3a9ca1e5-1b5c-46c9-a7ef-3e60d5e86d47/cannot-perform-the-operation-on-a-stopped-deployment

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this recently and found it was due to shutting down multiple VM's via the cloud service shutdown. This puts them in a shutdown state but does not deallocate them.

Portal solution: Go to the Cloud Services from menu > Click the name of the group there > Click start.

This takes them into an online state ready for you to connect (once they've booted of course).

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are unable to start the Azure Virtual Machine. Suggest you to try the below mentioned steps

• Restart the Virtual Machine from the Management Portal

• Resize the Virtual Machine from the Portal but ensure to Back up the Data in the Temporary Drive ( D:) since the data will be lost while Resizing.

• If the issue is still not fixed, please recreate the VM by retaining the attached Disk’s and attaching the same to the new VM

• If the issue still persists, you might want to recover the VM by attaching the OS Disk to another VM . Please refer to the below mentioned blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/11/20/recovering-azure-vm-by-attaching-os-disk-to-another-azure-vm.aspx

Comment: dead link. is there another way to access the article?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto this issue today, and although it has been four years, this was the first post I found about it. Someone might be helped by this new trick I found to solve this.

I simply set the **auto-shutdown schedule** very close to the current time so that it could shuts the virtual machine properly. That did the trick! I could restart it afterwards without trouble.

Saved me the trouble of creating a new resource.

Comment: This worked for me. Simple but effective. It seems like if the stop-button is disabled but the auto-shutdown works, this should be an easy fix for them, so it's weird that this problem has been around for years without being fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I encountered was all the buttons disabled after stopping the vm from azure portal.
[image]

What I did was go to **Operations -> Change Tracking**, for my case, our vm didn't enabled change tracking before this, and Im able to start vm from here. Vm goes back to normal, buttons reenabled after that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the following

- Resize the virtual machine (But backup the data first)
- Delete the virtual machine, but keep the attached disks. Then recreate the virtual machine and attach the old disks to it.
- Use Powershell to force start the virtual machine

I have had the same issue a few times, and the Powershell option always saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same problem.
So I did the following things-

1. Deleted the VM, Created a new virtual machine and attached the old disk.
2. Forcely Powered on VM using powershell.

Going with Resizing option is your choice however.